# conky execi doesn't execute on startup

Tags: conky

In my .conkyrc file I use some shell-scripts and call it via {execi}.

The problem is it doesn't execute these scripts on startup, e.g. get_public_ip.sh doesn't need to get called every 30 seconds like the get_cpu_temp.sh, so I use:

```
{exceci 3600 get_public_ip.sh}
```

with this command I have to wait one hour until I get my public IP because conky doesn't call the script on startup!

How can I configure conky so it will call all {execi} lines on startup?

Comment: Strange setup. The machine should run some kind of DHCP client whenever it gets connected to a newtork, not some cobbled together script each hour.

Comment: yes it does but to the DHCP request goes to my wlan router and there I get 192.168.x.x! I want to display my public IP in conky, like 81.192.xxx.xxx

Comment: Then you should configure that IP as static, or configure the DHCP server to asign it to your machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell `execi` *should* work, not sure why it doesn't. In any case, I get `conky`to show my public IP as follows:

```
${texeci 3600 wget -qO - http://cfajohnson.com/ipaddr.cgi}
```

Try replacing `execi` with `texeci`, see if that helps.

Another possible problem is that `conky` may be loaded before your connection is established. If so, it *will* run your `execi` command on startup but it will get no result since you are not connected yet. I get around this type of problem by launching `conky` through a wrapper script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 20
conky
```